# Evaluate value nested in foreach and if methods in chess

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm programming a game of chess in Unity3D and I'm trying to write the method to determine whether or not the king is in check by figuring out which king is the current player-to-move's king and then comparing the kings position against the list of threatened squares from the opponent.

I've tried using `IndexOf`, `Intersect()`, and a few other things, but I can't seem to get it to match properly. If I insert `Debug.Log` or `Console.Write` within the `if()` statement, the king's position returns correctly--but it doesn't seem to evaluate as true even when `threatenedSquares` has the king's position in it.

Current code EDITED WITH threatenedSquares returning a list of values via the debugger:

```
        public bool IsKingThreatened()
    {
        Vector2Int kingPosition;
        GameObject[] kings;
        kings = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("King");

        foreach(GameObject king in kings)
        {
            if (currentPlayer.pieces.Contains(king))
            {
                kingPosition = GridForPiece(king);
                Debug.Log("King position: " + kingPosition);
                Debug.Log("Player: " + currentPlayer.name);
                foreach(Vector2Int p in currentPlayer.threatenedSquares)
                {
                    Debug.Log(p);
                }

                if (currentPlayer.threatenedSquares.Contains(kingPosition))
                {
                    Debug.Log("King at " + kingPosition + "is threatened");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Output:

```
Debug.Log: King position:  (Correct coordinates)
Debug.Log: Player: (active player)

kingThreatened == false;
```

currentPlayer.pieces is a `List<GameObject>` and
threatenedSquares is a `List<Vector2Int>`

EDIT: cleaned it up a bit as per @clarkitech's point; however it still always returns false:

```
    public bool IsKingThreatened()
    {
        Vector2Int kingPosition;
        GameObject[] kings;
        kings = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("King");

        foreach (GameObject king in kings)
        {
            if (currentPlayer.pieces.Contains(king))
            {
                kingPosition = GridForPiece(king);

                return threatenedSquares.Contains(kingPosition);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: When are you printing `kingthreatened == false`? There's nothing in your code to show where that happens

Comment: I have a another debug log after the method is called elsewhere in the code that does `Debug.Log`(IsKingThreatened)`

Comment: Okay, and where do you assign to `IsKingThreatened`?

Comment: Every time a player's turn starts, there's a method to enter the state of their turn that 1) edits the threatenedSquares list, and 2) calls IsKingThreatened.

Comment: Are you sure that the type for `threatenedSquares` is `IEquatable` here?  It could be that _always_ returns false as well because it doesn't know how to compare those two objects.

Comment: @clarkitect I can't confirm 100% at the moment but I do believe Unity's `Vector2Int` does implement `IEquatable<Vector2Int>`

Comment: Well, then the next question is what's inside the `GridForPiece` method --but I believe @Metapilgrim confirmed with logging that it _does_ provide the correct grid object.  I'd maybe inspect or log a serialized `kingPosition` and log a serialized `threatenedSquares.FirstOrDefault()` to see what's really up.

Comment: Okay. The issue seems to be one of ordering outside of this. The code blocks suggested here independently work, but it appears that I have a timing issue. It looks like it's adding to threatenedSquares and then dropping the list when otherPlayer swaps with currentPlayer

Answer (score 4):

You're always returning false.  Here's a simplified view of the problem area.

```
    foreach (GameObject king in kings)
    {
        if (currentPlayer.pieces.Contains(king))
        {
            // your logic with no exit condition
        }
    }
    return false;
```

Once the loop completes, it will *always* `return false` unless you instead `return kingThreatened`

I would make this a little more direct, but I'm guessing a little bit about the properties on your game pieces.

```
public bool isKingThreatened => currentPlayer.pieces
    .Where(x => x.HasTag("king"))
    .Where(x => threatenedSquares.Contains(GridForPiece))
    .Any();
```

The pieces owned by `currentPlayer` that have tag `"king"` and where that piece's location is within `threatenedSquares` collection.

Comment: That makes sense. I've cleaned it up and added a return statement that should return true if the king is in check...but it still always returns false. See above.

Comment: @Metapilgrim: I'd suggest putting a breakpoint on your `return` statement and inspecting the `threatenedSquares` and `kingPosition` values.

Comment: Ah! So I copied @StriplingWarrior's second code blck (changing GridForPiece(king) to GridForPiece(currentKing)) and ran the debugger. threatenedSquares.Count is coming back as 0. I'm going to roll back my code to something that actually was returning the full list of threatenedSquares.

Answer (score 1):

Clarkitect is correct about the problem with your logic, but the root of the problem is arguably that your code is complicated enough to make it easy to make that kind of a mistake in the first place.

I'd simplify things like so:

```
public bool IsKingThreatened()
{
    GameObject[] kings = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("King");
    return kings
        .Where(king => currentPlayer.pieces.Contains(king))
        .Select(GridForPiece)
        .Any(kingPosition => threatenedSquares.Contains(kingPosition));
}
```

Or perhaps:

```
public bool IsKingThreatened()
{
    GameObject currentKing = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("King")
        .Single(king => currentPlayer.pieces.Contains(king));
    Vector2Int kingPosition = GridForPiece(kingPosition);
    return threatenedSquares.Contains(kingPosition);
}
```

Comment: Agreed.  Having the single path to `return` would remove a good bit of ambiguity.